# How do you test junit tests

Tags: java, junit

How do we test the junit test cases we wrote? I thought manually testing ie create test data and asserting expected and actual values are okay is fine. But recently I have encountered a situation where junit tests were passing but the particular SUT code was failing during UI testing (that means the junit tests failed to guard the bug).

Comment: [Test driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). It doesn't help after the fact, but writing tests as (before) you write the production code ensures that the tests are testing what you think they're testing.

Comment: If you find the need to test your tests, something has gone hopelessly wrong.

Comment: The first rule of testing software: Tests can only show the presence of a bug, not the absence of it. The second rule of testing software: unless the software does a simple logical operation, exhaustive testing is not practically possible.http://www.testingexcellence.com/seven-principles-of-software-testing/

Answer (score 3):

If your tests are passing, but the actual *code* that the tests were meant to cover is *failing*, then one of two things has happened:

- The test suite hasn't adapted to cover that *specific* use case, or
- The tests written to cover that specific use case are insufficient.

In any case, you need to **rewrite your tests**.  Having a test suite which doesn't allow you to guard against specific aberrant behaviors makes your *entire* test suite worthless.

You do also mention that it fails explicitly during UI tests.  This could result from a disconnect of expectations between the UI and the backend testing.  In that event, either align the backend tests with the UI's actual inputs, or look to implement an integration test which covers the UI's workflow.

Answer (score 1):

> How do we test the junit test cases we wrote?

You should not.
Unit test are not infallible but testing tests makes no sense.

You should consider automatic tests as executable specifications.
Generally, if your specifications are wrong, you are stuck.
For automatic testing it is exactly the same thing.

To avoid this kind of problem or at least reduce it, I favor:

- review of code and testing code with peers of the development team.
- completing unit tests by integration and business test validated by the business team.
- continuous improvement of automatic tests.

  It is simple : as soon as a hole is detected in UI manual testing, an automatic test should be updated if the test exists but some checks are missing or else a new test should be created if the test is missing.

Comment: @Makoto Sorry, I have not finished yet.

Comment: Fair enough, but could you not use HTML line breaks?  Kinda throws things off.

Answer (score 1):

To verify quality of unit tests personally I use following techniques:

1. Coverage metrics. It's good idea to have good line and branch coverage. But it's usually not possible to have 100% line coverage, and coverage itself doesn't guarantee that code was actually tested rather simply called from test class.
2. Test code review. Personally I prefer writing tests with clear structure 'setup - run - assert'. If 'run' or 'assert' steps are missing, then there is something wrong with the test.
3. [Mutation testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing). There are frameworks which allow you to modify your production code in some simple way (*apply mutators on code*), then run your unit tests on modified code, and if no test fails, this code is not tested or tests are bad. For Java I use [PIT Mutation Testing](http://pitest.org/).

Also, sometimes it makes sense to apply not just unit tests but also some other testing techniques - manual testing, integration testing, load testing, etc.

Answer (score -1):

> I have encountered a situation where junit tests were passing but the
>   particular SUT code was failing.

Your unit tests should NOT miss the coverage of any method's functionality or their side effects. This is where the Code coverage tools like [Cobertura](http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/) play the role, it is NOT that the tests are passing, but we need to ensure that the each of the method's and their side effects have been unit tested/covered properly.

> No, code coverage is just as bad a placebo here. You can have 100%
>   line coverage but still be in the same fix the OP is in?

Tools like Cobertura are there at least to find how much percentage of the code coverage we are doing, but, you will get even more bugs if you don't bother about tests coverage.

The main point is that these coverage tools don't tell you whether your internal business requirements have been really met or not.

Comment: No, code coverage is just as bad a placebo here.  You can have 100% line coverage but still be in the same fix the OP is in.

Comment: I agree with you, BUT, you will get even more bugs if you don't bother about coverage

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with that philosophy.  Code coverage as a crutch indicates long and complex code.  Code that is simpler in intent and design doesn't have many lines, or much branching code.